# How to choose initial (x0,y0) point to approximate a solution of a system of non-linear equations using newton method?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

I'm studying Newton's method for solving a system of non-linear equations.

A system of non-linear equations, whose (one of the) solutions is ($x^*$, $y^*$):
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
% R & L   &  R & L   &  R & L 
  f(x,y) = 0 \\
  g(x,y) = 0
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation*}
Can be approximated by a system of linear equations using newton's expansion, around a chosen($x_0$, $y_0$) starting point, whose solution is a ($x_{1}$, $y_1$) point, which is closer to ($x^*$, $y^*$) than ($x_0$, $y_0$).
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
% R & L   &  R & L   &  R & L 
  f_x(x_0, y_0).(x-x_o) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0) = -f(x_0,y_0) \\
  g_x(x_0, y_0).(x-x_o) + g_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0) = -g(x_0,y_0)
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation*}

The process can be repeated as many times as wished, obtaining ($x_{k+1}$, $y_{k+1}$) points that converge to ($x^*$, $y^*$) each iteration more.

I got the theory, but I'm struggling to apply it to a real example.

Take:

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
% R & L   &  R & L   &  R & L 
  x² + y² = 2 \\
  x² - y² = 1
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation*}

It's a simple system, took for educational purposes, whose solutions are:

1. ($\sqrt1.5$, $\sqrt0.5$)
2. ($\sqrt1.5$, -$\sqrt0.5$)
3. (-$\sqrt1.5$, $\sqrt0.5$)
4. (-$\sqrt1.5$, -$\sqrt0.5$)

How do I choose ($x_0$, $y_0$)? Does it need to satisfy f or g? If I choose a point that satisfies f, it wont satisfy g, unless its (x*, y*). I'm really confused.

Comment: @Moo Thanks! I can choose a point even if its not part of neither f or g?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MOO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use my answer to [Newton method to solve nonlinear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094608/newton-method-to-solve-nonlinear-system) as a guide and you can see another example using this method.

The regular Newton-Raphson method is initialized with a starting point $x_0$ and then you iterate $\tag 1x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

In higher dimensions, there is an exact analog. We define:

$$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x_1,x_2) \\  f_2(x_1,x_2)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^2 + x_2^2-2 \\   x_1^2-x_2^2 -1  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

The derivative of this system is the $2x2$ Jacobian given by:

$$J(x_1,x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_1 & 2 x_2\\ 2 x_1  & -2x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

The function $G$ is defined as:

$$G(x) = x - J(x)^{-1}F(x)$$

and the functional Newton-Raphson method for nonlinear systems is given by the iteration procedure that evolves from selecting an initial $x^{(0)}$ and generating for $k \ge 1$ (compare this to $(1)$),

$$x^{(k)} = G(x^{(k-1)}) = x^{(k-1)} - J(x^{(k-1)})^{-1}F(x^{(k-1)}).$$

We can write this as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k)}\\x_2^{(k)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k-1)}\\x_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}y_1^{(k-1)}\\y_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}$$

where:

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1^{(k-1)}\\y_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}= -\left(J\left(x_1^{(k-1)},x_2^{(k-1)}\right)\right)^{-1}F\left(x_1^{(k-1)},x_2^{(k-1)}\right)$$

Here is a starting vector:

$$x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(0)}\\x_2^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1.5\\1.5\end{bmatrix}$$

You should end up with a solution that looks something like (you can do the iteration formula steps as it converges very quickly):

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.22474\\0.707107\end{bmatrix}$$

As another example, I chose the following starting point

$$x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(0)}\\x_2^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-150.\\150.\end{bmatrix}$$

The iterates still converged pretty quickly and these initial choices were way outside the actual roots (we do not always have such luck - see update below) as

$$\{-150.,150.\},\{-75.005,75.0017\},\{-37.5125,37.5042\},\{-18.7762,18.7587\},\{-9.42807,9.3927\},\{-4.79358,4.72297\},\{-2.55325,2.41442\},\{-1.57037,1.31075\},\{-1.26278,0.846107\},\{-1.22532,0.718524\},\{-1.22475,0.707197\},\{-1.22474,0.707107\},\{-1.22474,0.707107\}$$

Of course, for a different starting vector you are going to get a different solution and perhaps no solution at all.

For comparison, the four exact roots are

$$\left(x=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\land \left(y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lor y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\lor \left(x=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\land \left(y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lor y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

**Update** What are approaches to choosing starting points?

Typically, you just choose a point at random. You could also use a contour plot and see if there are points of intersection as a guide in selecting the starting points (it depicts the four points of intersection, that is, the roots).

[image]

Sometimes, when solving nonlinear equations, coming up with a good initial guess is a bit of an art, that often requires some problem-specific understanding. If you start too far from a root, Newton’s method can sometimes take a large step, far outside the validity of the Taylor approximation, and this can actually make the guess worse. You can read some additional thoughts at [How to choose an initial value for a multidimensional equation while using Newton-Raphson method to solve it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718061/how-to-choose-an-initial-value-for-a-multidimensional-equation-while-using-newto).

Convergence for the multidimensional Newton’s method is also quadratic (under some assumptions similar to those in the one-dimensional case), but the same and other issues can occur. You can see a proof and some comments at [Prove or disprove - Newton's method convergence in higher dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157732/prove-or-disprove-newtons-method-convergence-in-higher-dimensions).

Comment: It seems to me this doesn’t really answer the question _How do I choose $(x_0, y_0)$?_

Comment: @Aruralreader: Good point. I left it out because in the comments I wrote "Typically, you just choose a point at random. You could do a contour plot and see if there are points of intersection and use that as a guide." I will add more details to the answer.